# Sample OpenIdProviderMvc always responses with XRDS file

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I run project OpenIdProviderMvc from DotNetOpenAuth.Samples. It started whithout any problems, i can go to `http://localhost:4864/` and aplication displays action Home/Index.
But after first authentication from relying party (in my case OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc which runs in second instance of Visual Studio) when i try to send request to `http://localhost:4864/` the provider responses whit XRDS file, not view Home/Index as i expected. If i send request to `http://localhost:4864/Home/Index` all is ok.

Why XRDS file is sended when i request to root link of application?

I want to include this openId provider into my application, but this unexpected behaviour makes it impossible.

EDIT1:
I found that XRDS file is cached so it is always outputed. But when i remove from view which generates this file line

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="86400" VaryByParam="none" Location="Any" %>--%>
```

the OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc app displays error:

> No OpenID endpoint found.

---

Solved: I have set cache duration to 1 and now everything works as i expected.